# HABTM association between models named with underscore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have got the following problem:
My Rails app has many models, but I have a problem with the association between two of them:

```
class RedArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :red_sections
end

class RedSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :red_articles
end
```

Seems to be a standard setup. But when I test the association for example with

```
RedArticle.first.red_sections
```

Then I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table
>   'clubago.red_articles_sections' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM
>   `red_articles_sections`

So my Rails looks for a table called `red_articles_sections` instead of `red_articles_red_sections` (which exists in my database). Does somebody know where this Problem comes from? I tried to rename the database to `red_articles_sections` and it worked, but I don't think that this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will this help

```
class RedArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :red_sections, join_table: "red_articles_red_sections"
end


class RedSection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :red_articles, join_table: "red_articles_red_sections"
end
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many (options)

Answer (score 0):

This is on purpose, actually. The [Rails docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many) explain it:

> If your tables share a common prefix, it will only appear once at the beginning. For example, the tables “catalog_categories” and “catalog_products” generate a join table name of “catalog_categories_products”.

So, your quick fix was correct. However, my personal recommendation would be to drop the `Red` prefix from both of your models -- unless you have a different model named `Article` in your schema somewhere, does the `Red` really add anything?

[Athar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31660269/5154683) would also work, if you want to keep the old join table name.